# Understanding Angular state provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've bought an app template to help me understand Angular, and I'm looking at the `$stateProvider`. Currently, I have:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/app/dashboard-v1');
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/app',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/app.html'
    })
    .state('app.dashboard-v1', {
        url: '/dashboard-v1',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/app_dashboard_v1.html',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                function( $ocLazyLoad ){
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load(['js/controllers/chart.js']);
            }]
        }
    })
```

So, navigating to `/app/dashboard-v1` gives the dashboard view. In order to get rid of the `/app` prefix in the url, I remove `app` from the url in the `app` state:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .otherwise('/dashboard-v1');
$stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/app.html'
    })
    .state('app.dashboard-v1', {
        url: '/dashboard-v1',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/app_dashboard_v1.html',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                function( $ocLazyLoad ){
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load(['js/controllers/chart.js']);
            }]
        }
    })
```

But this doesn't load the templates as expected - I expected it to give exactly the same result, but with `/dashboard-v1` instead of `app/dashboard-v1`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're telling the route provider to go to a /dashboard-v1 but you no longer have any state which matches that url.  If you want to preserve the functionality as before you'll need to change the url in the state provider back to /dashboard-v1.  If you can give more detail of what you're trying to achieve I could probably improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had thought that changing the parent state ("app") url would achieve what I want, which is to access the dashboard via `/dashboard-v1` rather than 'app/dashboard-v1`.

Comment: I've just figured this out - the url in the `app` state should be `''`, not `'/'`.